# Wildfly-servlet distribution and AsyncResponse injection

Tags: rest, wildfly

Could someone confirm if I can use Wildfly-servlet only distribution to do asynchronous Rest calls? Seems like JAX-RS injects an instance of AsyncResponse whenever it sees @Suspended AsyncResponse, but with Wildfly-servlet injection is not available.  I am wondering if there is anyway around this.

Answer (score 0):

No WildFly Servlet is essentially just Undertow with WildFly Core. You can only use servlets and JSP's.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use it if you bundle Resteasy in your application.